# Where should we put our enums?

Tags: c#, java, c++, coding-style, enums

A short question that always bother me when I develop in Java. I actually use a lot of different enums and I am never sure of where I should put them. Usually, I create a special package named *enumeration* which I am quite sure is not the best practice. Should I put my enums directly in the same package than the group of class it most belong to?

Also, would it be the same for another language (C# or C++)?

Comment: .NET and C++ don't have packages, so this isn't entirely relevant to them.

Comment: @Oded the equivalent would be namespaces

Comment: In .NET, you put it in the namespace that it is used in.

Comment: You have to decide on the language. The answers would be quite different.

Comment: FWIW, the original question had Java in the title.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213637/where-is-the-best-place-to-locate-enum-types.  And I agree with the answer there.  The essence is the same for C# or Java, just namespace vs. package.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo - There are subtle differences. Packages are both logical _and_ physical units. Namespaces are logical (assemblies are physical).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best descision depends on how the enumeration is used.

E.g.

- if the enumeration is only used in one class, you can make it an inner class to that class
- if the enumeration is used by one class (e.g. `A`) more than others (e.g. the others call methods on `A` that have parameters of type of the enumeration; you might want to put it in the same package/namespace as `A` is in.

In general, find the best package/namespace based on where its used most

Answer (score 1):

When my application grew large enough, we actually migrated all of our enums to a single C# csproj/DLL file.  The file was very small, but because it was completely detached from all applications, it meant that:

- People always knew where to look to find an enum
- Reduced likelihood of "recreating" the same enum twice
- It could be used in both server applications and client applications directly to ensure that both were using identical definitions

I don't claim this is the best solution for everyone, but it really reduced our hassle level.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration and placement of enums follow the same rules as the declaration and placement of other variables regarding visibility and block-hierarchy. That means if you put the code of an enum inside a class A then that enum will belong to class A.

I am also using enums extensively and what I try to do in order to create a clean and correct model is to put the enum where it closely belongs because most of the time I will use it at this place - no matter if it's a namespace, a clas or a nested class. When I am using the enum from anywhere else I will have to explicitly need to use the parent scope of the enum which again models the semantics - if coded correctly - best.

So it's primarily a question of object-related real-world mapping, semantic consistency and code-reusability I would say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Java or C#, but in C++, I always put in C++ class specification if its strongly related to class. If it's used across different classes, I keep it in a separate header file ( in a separate namespace where system specifics enums and constants are kept).

Answer (score 0):

Use nested namespaces (see other thread here: [Fuller information on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213637/where-is-the-best-place-to-locate-enum-types/11567737#11567737)). The main thing is it reduces dependencies outside the subsystem in question.

So in the enum header file you get:

```
// MyEnumHeader.h
// Consolidated enum header file for this dll,lib,subsystem whatever.
namespace MyApp
{
  namespace MyEnums
  {
    enum SomeEnum { EnumVal0, EnumVal1, EnumVal2 };
  };
};
```

And then in the class header file you get:

```
// MyInterfaceHeader.h
// Class interfaces for the subsystem with all the expected dependencies.

#include "MyEnumHeader.h"

namespace MyApp
{
  class MyInterface
  {
  public:
    virtual void DoSomethingWithEnumParam (MyEnums::SomeEnum enumParam) = 0;
  };
};
```

Then in client code use "using" syntax:

```
using namespace MyApp::MyEnums;
```